# AsyncTask GeoCoder sometimes crashes?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Can anyone help me figure out why sometimes the AsyncTask GeoCoder SOMETIMES works, and other times, crashes? I've browsed through some of the posts related to this topic, but doesnt seem like I can relate to it.

Heres MyCode:

```
public class statuspage extends MapActivity {

LocationManager locationManager;
MapView mapView;
Criteria criteria;
Location location;
Geocoder gc;
Address address;

String bestProvider;
String LOCATION_SERVICE = "location";
String addressString = "No address found";
String lonLat = "lonLat";
StringBuilder sb;
StringBuilder ssb;

private MapController mapController;
private MyLocationOverlay myLocation;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.statuspage);

    // Get Mapping Controllers etc //
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mapController = mapView.getController();
    mapController.setZoom(17);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    // Add the MyLocationOverlay //
    myLocation = new MyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);
    mapView.getOverlays().add(myLocation);
    myLocation.enableMyLocation();

    // Animates the map to GPS Position //
    myLocation.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            mapController.animateTo(myLocation.getMyLocation());
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {

    // Executes GeoCoding AsyncTask //
    new GeoCoder().execute();

    // Location Manager Intiation
    locationManager = (LocationManager) statuspage.this
            .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    criteria = new Criteria();

    // More accurate, GPS fix.
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE); // More accurate, GPS fix.
    bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
    if (location != null) {

        // Latitude and Longitude TextView
        TextView etlongitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etlongitude);
        TextView etlatitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etlatitude);

        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();

        // Latitude and Longitude TextView Display Coordinates //
        etlongitude.setText((longitude) + "");
        etlatitude.setText((latitude) + "");

        // locationManager.removeUpdates((LocationListener) location);
        locationManager = null;

    } else {

    }

    return false;
}

class GeoCoder extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Log.d("AsyncTask", "GeoCoder-doInBackGround");

        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();

        gc = new Geocoder(statuspage.this, Locale.getDefault());
        try {

            List<Address> addresses = gc.getFromLocation(latitude,
                    longitude, 1);

            sb = new StringBuilder();
            if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
                address = addresses.get(0);
                int noOfMaxAddressLine = address.getMaxAddressLineIndex();
                if (noOfMaxAddressLine > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                        sb.append(address.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
                    }
                    addressString = sb.toString();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            addressString = e.toString();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        TextView scrollview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scrollview);
        scrollview.setText("Current Position:" + "\n"
                + "(Accurate to 500 meters)" + "\n" + (addressString));

        Log.d("AsyncTask", "GeoCoder-onPostExecute");
        return;
    }

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    myLocation.enableMyLocation();
    //new GeoCoder().execute();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    myLocation.disableMyLocation();
    //new GeoCoder().cancel(true);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    // Button OnClick Vibrating Service
    Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

    // Vibrate Service
    vib.vibrate(50);

    startActivity(new Intent(statuspage.this, AgentPortalActivity.class));
    statuspage.this.finish();

    /** Fading Transition Effect */
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);

    return;

}
 }
```

Here are My Logs:

```
 04-18 08:36:42.812: I/Maps.MyLocationOverlay(18136): Request updates from gps
 04-18 08:36:42.812: I/Maps.MyLocationOverlay(18136): Request updates from network
 04-18 08:36:42.859: I/MapActivity(18136): Handling network change notification:CONNECTED
 04-18 08:36:42.859: E/MapActivity(18136): Couldn't get connection factory client
 04-18 08:36:42.910: D/AsyncTask(18136): GeoCoder-doInBackGround
 04-18 08:36:42.972: W/dalvikvm(18136): threadid=25: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015578)
 04-18 08:36:42.995: E/AndroidRuntime(18136): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #15
 04-18 08:36:42.995: E/AndroidRuntime(18136): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
 04-18 08:36:42.995: E/AndroidRuntime(18136):   at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
 04-18 08:36:42.995: E/AndroidRuntime(18136):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
 04-18 08:36:42.995: E/AndroidRuntime(18136):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
 04-18 08:36:42.995: E/AndroidRuntime(18136):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
 04-18 08:36:42.995: E/AndroidRuntime(18136):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
 04-18 08:36:42.995: E/AndroidRuntime(18136):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
 04-18 08:36:42.995: E/AndroidRuntime(18136):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
 04-18 08:36:42.995: E/AndroidRuntime(18136):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
 04-18 08:36:42.995: E/AndroidRuntime(18136): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 04-18 08:36:42.995: E/AndroidRuntime(18136):   at com.jetdelivery.mobile.statuspage$GeoCoder.doInBackground(statuspage.java:115)
 04-18 08:36:42.995: E/AndroidRuntime(18136):   at com.jetdelivery.mobile.statuspage$GeoCoder.doInBackground(statuspage.java:1)
 04-18 08:36:42.995: E/AndroidRuntime(18136):   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
 04-18 08:36:42.995: E/AndroidRuntime(18136):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
 04-18 08:36:42.995: E/AndroidRuntime(18136):   ... 4 more
```

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 3):

From the page [Geocoder.getFromLocation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocationName%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20double%29)

> Returns a list of Address objects. Returns **null** or empty list if no matches were found or there is no backend service available.

So you need to check for null before:

```
if (addresses.size() > 0)
```

Comment: If it does return null, then he'd have to check if addresses!=null fisrt, otherwise he'll crashes anyway

Comment: Not too sure I understand whats going on. So I have to check if getFromLocation != null?

Comment: Yes if addresses  == null skip the rest of the code t that refers to it.

Comment: I have set up if addresses == null with a toast message. Still crashes once in  awhile. am I supposed to set something else up?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a (IOException e) crash every time on geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1); 
However, I simply turned on/off my samsung phone and it worked...

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

try {

```
    List<Address> addresses = gc.getFromLocation(latitude,
            longitude, 1);
    sb = new StringBuilder();
        if (addresses!=null && addresses.size() > 0) {
            address = addresses.get(0);
            int noOfMaxAddressLine = address.getMaxAddressLineIndex();
            if(noOfMaxAddressLine > 0){
                for (int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++){
                   sb.append(address.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
                }
                addressString = sb.toString();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        addressString = e.toString();
    }
```

Comment: Sorry on the late reply Saneesh. I've tried your code you suggested to me but it still does the same. =/

Comment: Can you give the new logcat output

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply ! and I really do appreciate all your help. Heres my new Log

Comment: Can you post the 115th line in statuspage.java?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10235/discussion-between-saneesh-cs-and-john-nguyen)